# Images appear too large in VS Template Web Forms

Tags: image, templates, webforms

I opened new project from Visual Studio template - Web Forms application.

If I put ImageButton in existing Web Form using Master Page image appears too large and if I put ImageButton on Web Form without Master Page image is normal.

The same thing goes with other controls that include images.

Any information is appreciated...